# Instantiate a class from a config file. Where should the parse function go?

Tags: design, python, programming-practices, class

I have a class in python that is instantiated from the values of a (json) config file. I was wondering what is the best practise to do that (if there is a best practise and is not just a matter of personal preference).

- I call a read_config function (which is defined outside the class) in my main, that parses my configuration file and returns the configuration as a dictionary. Then, I instantiate the class using this dictionary.

or

- I instantiate the class by giving the configuration file name. In my class there is the read_config method that sets my instance variables.

In the first method I find positive that I am a little bit more flexible from where I get my config data. It could be a file, or even a hard-coded dictionary. Is there any software design rule that should be followed or it really doesn't matter?

Comment: The most relevant principle at play here is probably "Single Responsibility."  You will have to decide if it's your class' responsibility to parse JSON.  Normally that parsing would take place somewhere else, and you would pass the result of that parse (i.e. a DTO) to your class being configured.  A dictionary also works.

Answer (score -2):

The design pattern for constructing objects is called the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

My suggestion is you create an abstract factory that takes the parsed dictionary and returns the instantiated object (in fp pseudocode):

```
// FooFactory is a function that takes a dictionary and produces a Foo
FooFactory = Dict => Foo

def defaultFooFactory(dict: Dict): Foo
    // from dict
    return Foo(...)
```

To address where the JSON file should be parsed, you can implement `FooFactory` for that:

```
def jsonFooFactory(fileName: String, delegate: FooFactory)(dict: Map[String, Object]): Foo =
    // load json file from fileName and merge it with passed dict
    combinedDict = ...
    return delegate(combinedDict)
```

Then at your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) you should construct your chosen factory:

factory = jsonFooFactory("config.json", defaultFooFactory)

You can pass around your factory and create instances of `Foo` whenever you want:

```
factory(// overrides to json could be passed here)
```

The benefits of this pattern are:

- Follows single responsibility principle. A class shouldn't know how to instantiate itself
- Abstracts the construction of `Foo`. You can change how you instantiate `Foo` by implementing new `FooFactory`s.
- Adds an abstraction layer that decouples and improves testability

Comment: Ack...  Really? ....

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you gave me something more tangible I could defend my answer :)

Comment: `Follows single responsibility principle. A class shouldn't know how to instantiate itself` -- That's not what SRP means.  This is probably where your answer runs off the rails.

Comment: `Abstracts the construction of Foo. You can change how you instantiate Foo by implementing new FooFactorys` -- Why would you need this?

Comment: `Abstracts the construction of Foo. You can change how you instantiate Foo by implementing new FooFactorys` -- Again, why would you need this?  A dictionary provides more than sufficient abstraction for a general-purpose configuration mechanism.

Comment: All in all, it seems like a lot of boilerplate for dubious benefits.

Comment: "That's not what SRP means" -- SRP says that a class should only have one reason to change. If `Foo` knows how to instantiate itself then it will have two reasons to change-- 1. if `Foo`'s logic changes and 2. if `Foo`'s instantiation changes.

Comment: "Why would you need this?" As OP says, instantiation could happen from hard coded dictionary, JSON. The abstraction supports this and any other configuration mechanism you can think of. "A dictionary provides more than sufficient abstraction for a general-purpose configuration mechanism" that's why I chose the dictionary as my factory's parameter. Perhaps I don't know what you're saying

Comment: "All in all, it seems like a lot of boilerplate for dubious benefits" the main reason why I like my design is that each part is independently unit-testable. the parts being 1. parse json to dictionary 2. construction of `Foo` from dictionary 3. how configuration is overriden

Comment: Sounds like we need clarification from the OP that he's actually producing different objects based on the content of the JSON; it was my impression that the JSON merely sets members in the object, and that the object's type does not change.

Comment: Even if it is a factory, it could be satisfied with a simple Factory method, which is highly unit-testable.  If it's simple enough, it may not need to be unit tested at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60863/discussion-between-samuel-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: " SRP says that a class should only have one reason to change. If Foo knows how to instantiate itself then it will have two reasons to change-- 1. if Foo's logic changes and 2. if Foo's instantiation changes." sweet jesus, by that logic every single class needs a factory, every factory needs a factoryfactory, etc.

Comment: @whatsisname it depends how big you define a responsibility. "create object graph" may be a single responsibility of the composition root that uses factories to create the objects